# re-use strings without losing formatting from the original string-set

Tags: css, css-paged-media

I am setting a string for a chapter title using string-set.

When I add content and re-use that string through my document, I would like it to maintain the original formatting of my `h1` (`font-weight:bold`).

How can I do that? I cannot just style the content because the rest of the content("My Document Title") should not be bold.

At the moment, I am using the string as part of a header:

```
 h1{
       font-weight:bold;
       string-set:chaptitle1 self;
   }

@page chap1 {       
   @top-left { 
      content: "My Document Title" string(chaptitle1) ; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand your question but you should be able to define properties to @top-left region.

example:

```
    @page chap1 { 
        @top-left {
            content: "My Document Title" string(chaptitle1) ; 
            background-color: #ff0000;
            color: white;
        }
    }
```

This would show the background of the text red and the text white. This absolutely works in PrinceXML.

Comment: I was hoping to format "My Document Title" as you have done here but have the string retain its original formatting rather than take on the formatting defined for the content. For example "My Document Title" would be bold but the text from the strong would be italic.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. Only content is being copied not styling.